# Normally embedded subgroups reducing in a Hall system

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

A Hall system of $G$ is a set $\Sigma$ of Hall subgroups of $G$ satisfying the following two properties:

-For each $\pi$ divisor if $|G|$, $\Sigma$ contains excatly one Hall $\pi$-subgroup $G_{\pi}$.

-If $H,K \in \Sigma$, then $HK=KH$

Let $G$ a group, $U \leq G$ and $\Sigma$ a Hall system of $G$. In general $\Sigma \cap U$ is not a Hall system of $U$. But if $U$ is a normally embedded subgroup of $G$  this statement is true, why?

Thanks!

I think that we have to prove:

- That $G_{\pi} \cap U \in Hall_{\pi}(G)$, and that
- That $(U \cap G_{\pi_1})(U \cap G_{\pi_2})=(U \cap G_{\pi_2})(U \cap G_{\pi_1})$.

I have only been capable to see that if $G_{\pi} \perp U$ so $G_{\pi}U$ is a subgroup, $\frac{|G_{\pi}U|}{|G_{\pi}|}=\frac{|U|}{|G_{\pi} \cap U|}$ and $G_{\pi} \cap U$ is a $Hall_{\pi}(G)$, then I proove two statements. But I don't have this hypothesis.

Comment: What does it mean for a subgroup to be normally embedded? To you simply mean a normal subgroup?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, "A subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is said to be normally embedded in $G$ if, for every prime $p$ dividing the order of $H$, there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$." (Source: http://www.journal.shu.edu.cn/EN/abstract/abstract6824.shtml)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Ahh, ok. So by considering the product of those normal subgroups, this reduces to the case of $U$ being normal, and then it follows from the Hall-subgroups being conjugate, since the group has a Hall system.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, good! Please make it into an answer, for the benefit of OP.

Comment: What does $G_{\pi}\perp U$ mean?

Comment: @James: pretty literally that $G_\pi U$ is a subgroup. It means $G_\pi U = U G_\pi$; it is read “$G_\pi$ and $U$ permute.”

Comment: @Jack Schmidt, thanks. I had not seen that notation before.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, i don't understand. What normal subgroups are you referring to?

Comment: The ones whose existence is required by the definition.